# Python (NumPy) Arrays with Alternative Lengths which can not be predefined

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I'm currently working on a numerical python code (from scratch) to solve the following thought problem:

Imagine I have a 2D problem with a rigid ground, and a flexible layer on top of that, which is connected to the ground by equidistant spaced springs. On top of the flexible layer there is a cylinder, which is (if you like) glued to the edge of the flexible layer. Now the cylinder is rolled horizontally in numerous increments effecting an opening of the springs, starting from the edge.

Now my question concerns the following; as an effect of the balance between the combined spring forces and the moment applied to the cylinder a certain number of springs will be opened at equilibrium. This number of opened springs is not known in advance due to the nonlinearity of the problem. 
Furthermore, I wish not to model the whole geometry, but rather only take into accounts the relevant opened springs. During this process I would like, for example, to store the resultant forces in every opened spring corresponding to a certain moment increment.

---

Thus, in my opinion, the programming problem here is to:

- Create a Force `array` which contains for every increment a list of all the forces in the individual springs. The complexity emerges from the fact that this list does not have a predefined length nor is this length the same for every numerical increment. Note that in this case the number of increments is predefined through for example a `linspace`

---

I have been looking for a suitable Pythonic solution to this problem, but have not found one yet. I think the NumPy library should offer a convenient solution, but I lack the Python experience nor did I find a nice example. I am open to alternative approaches also, if more convenient in your opinion for the above described setup.

Currently, I have the following code example to showcase my approach:

```
from numpy import array , zeros , linspace

area = 2.0
Forces = []                 # Initialize complete Force array

for inc in range(1,4):
    stresses = linspace(0.,10.,inc)
    n = len(stresses)
    Forcej = zeros( n )     # Initialize Forces in current increment

    for i, stress in enumerate(stresses):
        Forcej[i] = area*stress

    print Forcej
    Forces.append(Forcej)


print Forces
```

Which outputs:

```
[ 0.]
[  0.  20.]
[  0.  10.  20.]
[array([ 0.]), array([  0.,  20.]), array([  0.,  10.,  20.])]
```

I suppose this is the desired outcome, but I'm thinking this is far from the most elegant solution, could anyone assist or comment on this example? Thanks already for considering my Question.

Comment: To help you, it'd be good to know where you're stuck. Is there a specific problem that keeps you from implementing your suggested solution with the array of forces of open springs? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited my question in response. Hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## More (num)pythonic

In python, you could write

```
    n = len(stresses)
    forcej = zeros( n )     # Initialize Forces in current increment

    for i, stress in enumerate(stresses):
        forcej[i] = area*stress
```

more elegantly as a list comprehension:

```
    forcej = array([ area * stress for stress in stresses ])
```

(Note that local variables in python are named in `lowercase` or `snake_case` by convention.)

But this is NumPy code, so let's just use scalar-vector multiplication instead:

```
    forcej = area * stresses
```

## Parallel vector computation with a <del>matrix</del> array of arrays

In your simple example, you can even compute the forces for all increments with a single scalar-matrix multiplication:

```
from numpy import array, linspace

area = 2.0

stresses = array([ linspace(0., 10., inc)  for inc in range(1, 4)])
print 'stresses =\n', stresses

forces = area * stresses
print
print 'forces =\n', forces
```

### Output

```
stresses =
[[ 0.] [  0.  10.] [  0.   5.  10.]]

forces =
[[ 0.] [  0.  20.] [  0.  10.  20.]]
```

Now, due to the varying sizes of its rows (each representing one increment), `stresses` isn't *really* a matrix, merely an array of arrays. Thus vector-matrix multiplication and matrix-matrix multiplication (which will be needed to write realistic, more complex calculations this concisely) would fail. (Scalar-matrix multiplication doesn't care about the matrix' shape. Apparently, it doesn't even have to be an [actual matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29).)

## Real matrices

But if I've understood you correctly, the size variation only stems from leaving away springs with zero stress in the respective increment.

So, if you want to use matrix arithmetic, instead of leaving zero entries away entirely, consider using [sparse matrices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html). Those avoid storing zero entries or doing calculations on them that'd just result in new zero entries anyway, but they still "know" that there are zero entries and what the complete shape of the matrix is (thus keeping matrix multiplication etc. meaningful).

Comment: Thanks, that was interesting and educational!

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I would recommend using a full array, so one column for every spring. In combination with for example the numexpr (https://code.google.com/p/numexpr) module, it is very easy and fast to extract all "active" springs at each timestep.

The reason I believe a full array is the way to go is because it maps really nice into how the underlying system handles memory access. So unless the number of springs are hugh (say >100000), I believe that dragging around a lot of zeros will not degrade the performance. Another option might be to look for efficient sparse matrices. I know SciPy has support for it. I am not sure if the matrix "profile" that you will get from your problem fits a sparse matrix very well.